# PHP/Python socket remote connection problems

Tags: php, python, sockets

I have this python code:

```
from socket import *
import threading
import thread
import time
import json

def handler(clientsock,addr):
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        data = clientsock.recv(65535);
        if not data:
            break
        object = json.loads(data)
        object['status'] = 1
        object['timestamp'] = time.time()
        output = json.dumps(object)        
        msg = output
        clientsock.send(msg)
    clientsock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = '192.168.0.28'
    PORT = 5555
    BUFSIZ = 65535
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

    serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.bind(ADDR)
    serversock.listen(5)

    while 1:
        print 'waiting for connection...'
        clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
        print '...connected from: ', addr
        thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsock, addr))
```

and this PHP code:

```
<?php 
/**
 *
 * PHP JSON Echo Server client
 *
*/
// python server socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, '192.168.0.28', 5555);
//Create a message, and send it to the server on $socket.
$data = array(
    'username' => 'sysadmin',
    'key' => '093ufj408xr0289u3r0x9u2m309x',
    'action' => 'login',
);
$json = json_encode($data);
socket_send($socket, $json, strlen($json), MSG_EOF);
$data = socket_read($socket, 65535);
$object = json_decode($data);
if($object->status) {
    echo '<p>Data received successfully.';
} else {
    echo '<p>Error. Data not read correctly!';
}
echo '<p>'.$data;
//Close the socket.
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

If I run it in my local network it works without a problem. But when I execute the PHP script on an external hosting it doesn't work anymore. I've changed the IP address to my WAN IP address and even to the DNS offered by the ISP. Nothing works.

This is the output:

```
Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in /home/usr/public_html/webclient.php on line 9

Warning: socket_send(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /home/usr/public_html/webclient.php on line 17

Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected in /home/usr/public_html/webclient.php on line 18
Error. Data not read correctly!
```

I tried scanning for open ports with this service: http://www.ipfingerprints.com/portscan.php and port 5555 is open. I also got a message from the server:

```
waiting for connection...
...connected from:  ('5.79.68.210', 36080)
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

on this code :

```
print '...connected from: ', addr
```

you cant use this code, for know open port you need use this code:

```
print '...connect from: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
```

only that

and you arnt using the sockets coorectly:

```
serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

use this its will be better:

```
serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: But this is not a solution. Why it isn't connecting to my python server if the 5555 port is open?

Comment: you are not correctly socket code: serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: use this code serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'socket'

Comment: dont use from socket import * use import socket directly

Comment: The problem persists. I can connect to the server only on local network. Outside it doesn't work. I get connection refused.

Comment: sorry , but your server have probleme on the port go check it because ii tryed script with my methode and its work

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it with the PHP code hosted externally?

Comment: i tryed the python code but i didnt check the PHP code because i am social enginner in perl python and c++ not PHP sorry :/